# Swift tableview not deleting correct row

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am working on a Twitter clone and have connected my app to Firestore. When I read the posts from Firestore I order them by "timestamp" (via firebase query) which makes my posts array ordered. I "insert" the new post at index 0 to make the newest post always on top, the problem is the array still keeps its indices (post at the bottom is index 0) which causes issues when trying to delete a post for example. What I'm looking for is keep the indices ordered as my posts.

Here is some code:

```
db.collection("Posts").document(doc.documentID).collection("Posts").order(by: "timestamp").addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
    
    for docu in documentSnapshot!.documents {
        
        let daate = docu.data()["timestamp"] as! Timestamp
        let mydbl = daate.dateValue().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
        
        let post = Post(id: docu.documentID, username: "@\(docu.data()["username"]!)", userId: doc.documentID , text: docu.data()["text"] as! String, timestamp: mydbl , numLikes: 0, numReposts: 0)
        
        let isDuplicate = tempPosts.contains(where: { $0.id == post.id })
        
        if(!isDuplicate){
            self.posts = tempPosts
            tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
        }
    }
    self.posts.removeAll()
    self.posts = tempPosts
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and here is my tableview cell deletion method, it has a callback from within the cell"

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
    
    cell.didDelete = { aCell in
        let currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: aCell)!
        self.posts.remove(at: currentIndexPath.row)
        print(currentIndexPath.row) // prints 0 when trying to delete the most recent post and removes the very bottom post since that is index 0
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [currentIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

I was thinking if there is a way to delete the selected cell with referring to something else rather than the index?

This is only a visual issue, the post is correctly deleted from the posts array but the wrong table cell is deleted (when refreshing everything looks right)

this is how a cell is deleted (which is why I dont want the swipe effect)

[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUuhQ.png)

[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFsYX.png)

[third screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ARva.png)

here is my cell code:

```
 import UIKit
 import FirebaseAuth
 import FirebaseFirestore

 class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var profileImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet public weak var username: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timestamp: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var postText: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!

public var postId: String!


var didDelete : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    profileImg.layer.cornerRadius = profileImg.bounds.height / 2
    profileImg.clipsToBounds = true
    
    postText.delegate = self

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func set(post: Post){
    username.text = post.username
    postText.text = post.text
    timestamp.text = post.createdAt.calenderTimeSinceNow()
    postId = post.id
    
    setPopupMenu(post: post)
}


func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        postText.resignFirstResponder()
        postText.isEditable = false
        postText.isScrollEnabled = false
        
        // update post
        
        
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func setPopupMenu(post: Post){
    let options = { (action: UIAction) in
        print(action.title)
        
        //
        if(action.title == "تعديل"){
            self.postText.isEditable = true
            self.postText.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.postText.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        else if(action.title == "حذف"){
            // delete tweet
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("Posts").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("Posts").document(post.id).delete() { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    self.didDelete!(self)
                }
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
    if(post.userId == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid){
        self.menuButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
            UIAction(title: "تعديل", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil"), handler: options),
            UIAction(title: "حذف", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive, handler: options),
        ])
    }
    else{
        self.menuButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
            UIAction(title: "حظر", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil"), handler: options),
            UIAction(title: "ميوت", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive, handler: options),
        ])
    }
    
    menuButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    }

  }
```

Comment: `didDelete` is a custom callback or your `PostTableViewCell` class. Please provide some code to get a better understanding of the `aCell` callback variable.

Comment: I presume that `aCell` is simply passed to the close as `self`, presumably in response to a button tap? As an aside, you should also support swipe left on the row to delete.  I don't understand your problem, however. You say that the array has most recent post in element 0; element 0 will always be the first (top) row in the table. I think your problem is how you keep replacing the entire array from the snapshot observer. You should just insert into element 0 of the existing array and reload that row.

Comment: Please add the code where you sort your `posts` array.

Comment: I just updated the question, I hope that the screenshot is helpful and makes sense of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I still don't follow where the various pieces of text come from, perhaps show your `cellForRowAt`, but I do note that you are performing Firestore operations in your cell. Do not do this. Your tableview controller or model object should handle this.  I think your problem comes from recreating the array and reloading the tableview each time in your snapshot listener. It is better to use `documentChanges` and just add or delete the affected rows.

Comment: Because your cell deletes the Firestore object, which will trigger the snapshot listener to recreate the array (asynchronously) and you then call your deletion closure which modifies the array you get inconsistent behaviour. I suggest that your cell "delete" menu should just call the closure. The closure should tell Firestore to delete the relevant item and then you wait for the snapshot listener to tell you the item has been deleted and update the table. You can update the cell appearance to indicate that a delete is in progress in your delete closure if you like.

Comment: That's what I thought of and actually did. Changing the firebase deletion to the callback in cellForRowAt helped! thanks!